# Eigenvalues from `prcomp`

Tags: r, pca, eigenvalues

I used `prcomp` to calculate the follow PCA values:

```
                PC1        PC2        PC3         PC4          PC5         PC6
logPower  0.6789041 -0.3370631  0.1337237  0.63152740 -0.092702676  0.01323106
logSpan   0.1475060  0.4778834  0.2150124  0.06127707 -0.048909835 -0.83515987
logLength 0.2128740  0.2307281  0.1568771 -0.27071156 -0.863486982  0.24071613
logWeight 0.5880074  0.2578687  0.2481639 -0.48182127  0.480207328  0.25182325
logSpeed  0.2291724 -0.6301924 -0.2741496 -0.53235281 -0.112767421 -0.42315895
logRange  0.2715571  0.3756882 -0.8800761  0.09264058 -0.009418365  0.04370613
```

The eigenvalues are located across the diagonal of this matrix, right? So the largest eigenvalue would be 0.6789041, second largest 0.4778834, and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, those are just eigenvectors. You need to save the output of `prcomp` into a variable and then look at the `sdev` component of that variable. Squaring the `sdev` component gets you the eigenvalues.

Comment: (+1) or you can use ```princomp(data)``` and square the values given in the output to obtain the eigenvalues.